# Any suggestions on how to go about proving that C generates infinite number of strings?

Tags: turing-machines

I know how to write pseudo code for proving C is CFG but how do i prove it generates infinite number of strings?

Prove that this language is Turing-decidable by designing Turing machine
pseudocode for a machine that decides it.

L1 = {〈C〉|C is a CFG and C generates infinite strings}

Comment: <C> is the input which has been encoded.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Instead of commenting your own question, it would be better if you would edit it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos someone commented on the post, and then deleted it..

Comment: I see. I missed that comment.

Comment: This question has been answered on cs.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561325/any-suggestions-on-how-to-go-about-proving-that-c-generates-infinite-number-of-s